# Sphinx Search how to use an empty before_match and after_match

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

Using Sphinx's [SNIPPET()](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-select) function, how can I remove any `before_match` and `after_match` from my query? I don't want anything wrapped around the matching text.

`SNIPPET(field, 'word', 'after_match=""', 'before_match=""')`

I've tried `after_match=""` but this adds literal quotes to the match.

I've tried `after_match=''"` but this fails

I've tried `after_match=` and this fails too

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just omit those options.

Comment: @hank that is incorrect. The default value is to wrap in `<b>` as stated in the documentation. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-buildexcerpts

Comment: Also you can use `CALL SNIPPETS` function which support empty `before_match` and `after_match` tags.

Comment: @hank how does that work with the mysql storage engine?

Comment: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse-snippets

Comment: I'm curious, why not simply omit the call to `snippets`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My only suggestion is just to set it to some innocuous string, and then remove in post. `'after_match=*'` then can do `<?php $str = str_replace('*','',$str);` sort of thing.

Or just use `strip_tags` style function to remove the automatic

```
<b>...</b>
```

:)